# Word for "fumo" but less thick, thin smoke

Tags: verbs, word-request, nuance

"Fumo" means "I smoke, steam or fume". But is there a word which indicates a thinner smoke or fume rises from me?

I'm looking for a word that incense could say about itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may not be perfect, but consider the verb [*vaporo*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2062090) as an alternative to *fumo*.
Comparing the underlying nouns [*vapor*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2062083) and [*fumus*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2023404) suggests that it is in the right direction.

One option to consider is using an adjective or an adverb.
I think [*tenuis*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2059045) is a suitable word for "thin" in the context of smoke.
The corresponding adverb is [*tenuiter*](http://latinlexicon.org/definition.php?p1=2059044), "thinly".

This makes me suggest:

> *Tenuiter fumo*. — I smoke thinly.
>   *Tenuis fumo*. — I am thin (masculine or feminine) and I smoke.

You can also use *vaporo* together with *tenuis*, but for some reason that sounds a bit off to me.

Comment: A great example from the *Georgica* uses *tenuis* along with *volucris* as an adjective: "Quae tenuem exhalat nebulam fumosque volucris"

Comment: 'presserat ora vapour' - Ovid II 283 - the hot smoke was choking her;

Comment: and another passage from Ovid Metamorphoses IV ,434- 'Styx nebulas exhalat iners '- "The sluggish Styx there exhales its vaporous breath"

Comment: and slightly different option - 'largis satiantur odoribus ignes' - "the fires are fed full with incense rich and fragrant" Ovid IV 759; so perhaps 'odoro' is suitable for incense

Answer (score 5):

[*Fumo, -are*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfumo) is a general word for something that is causing smoke or steam.

I cannot find a specialized word that refers to "thin smoke," but one alternative for incense is [*cremo, -are*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcremo) ("to burn, consume by fire"), which can be used in the passive for something that is being consumed. Here is an example of this usage in a traditional blessing of incense in the Roman Rite:

> Ab illo benedicaris, in cuius honore **cremaberis**.
>
> *May you be blessed by him in whose honor you will be burned.*

*Incensum crematur* seems to evoke the idea you are looking for.

Answer (score 5):

Not a single word, but a relevant passage from Ovid *Metamorphoses* 1.569-72:

> ...per quae Peneos ab imo
>   effusus Pindo spumosis volvitur undis,
>   deiectuque gravi tenues agitantia fumos
>   nubila conducit...

"...through which Peneus, flowing out from the base of Pindus, rolls with foamy waves, and in its heavy descent gathers clouds that stir up thin mists..."

Comment: Just wonderful!

Comment: I posted about this passage!

Answer (score 4):

L&S gives the noun *nidor, -oris*:

> m. cf. Gr. κνίσσα for κνιδια, a vapor, steam, smell, from any thing boiled, roasted, burned, etc.: *nidoris odores*, Lucr 6, 987: *galbaneus*, Verg. G. 3, 415: *pinguescant madidi laeto nidore Penates*, Mart. 7, 27, 5; Plin. 24, 15, 85, § 135: *nocturnumque recens exstinctum lumen ubi acri Nidore offendit nares*, Lucr. 6, 792: *ganearum nidor atque fumus*, Cic. Pis. 6, 13: *foedus quidam nidor ex adustā plumā*, Liv. 38, 7; Plin. 13, 1, 1, § 2: *captus nidore culinae*, Juv. 5, 162: *nidor e culinā*, said of a slave who hangs constantly about the kitchen, a fume of the kitchen, kitchen-companion, Plaut. Most. 1, 1, 5.

So that seems like a possible option, especially as it also has the associated verb *nidoro, -are*.

Though I also feel like there's got to be a reference to burning incense somewhere in the centuries of Church Latin. Unfortunately, I don't know that corpus—but to be honest I wouldn't be surprised if the verb the Church uses were *fumo*.